# How to add a latex package to R Journal template from rticle package in R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using [`rticle`](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles) package by RStudio to write an article in R using [`rmarkdown`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) package.
In the draft template there is an option

```
...
preamble: >
  % Any extra latex you need in the preamble
output: rticles::rjournal_article
...
```

Where I suspect I can add lines like `\usepackage{package_name}` or set a file name in which I load all desired Latex packages.

**The first approach**

I've tried to add one single package to `preamble` section like this but have stacked on an error

```
---
title: Capitalized Title Here
author:
  - name: Author One
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author1@work
  - name: Author Two
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author2@work
abstract: >
  An abstract of less than 150 words.
preamble: >
  \usepackage{rotating}
  % Any extra latex you need in the preamble
output: rticles::rjournal_article
---

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Your caption here}
   \begin{tabular}{ll}
    First First & First Second\\
    Second First & Second Second
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

**The first approach code end**

```
BŁĄD: running 'texi2dvi' on 'RJwrapper.tex' failed

LaTeX errors:
D:\RTCGA.data\Untitled\Untitled.tex:11: LaTeX Error: Environment sidewaystable 
undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
D:\RTCGA.data\Untitled\Untitled.tex:13: Package caption Error: \caption outside
 float.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
D:\RTCGA.data\Untitled\Untitled.tex:18: LaTeX Error: \begin{article} on input l
ine 20 ended by \end{sidewaystable}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
Dodatkowo: Warning message:
uruchomione polecenie '"C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf "RJwrapper.tex" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' otrzymało status 1 
Wykonywanie wstrzymane
```

I've seen the same `preamble` - ignoring behavior in this issue https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/11, but there was no response for that.
I've also tried to specify file named `header.tex` that contains a line `\usepackage{rotating}` in a last argument of a yaml like this but also there happend to be an error.

```
---
title: Capitalized Title Here
author:
  - name: Author One
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author1@work
  - name: Author Two
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author2@work
abstract: >
  An abstract of less than 150 words.
preamble: > 
   \usepackage{rotating}
output: 
   rticles::rjournal_article:
   includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---
BŁĄD: running 'texi2dvi' on 'RJwrapper.tex' failed

LaTeX errors:
D:\RTCGA.data\rticle\rticle.tex:145: LaTeX Error: Environment sidewaystable und
efined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
D:\RTCGA.data\rticle\rticle.tex:147: Package caption Error: \caption outside fl
oat.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
D:\RTCGA.data\rticle\rticle.tex:192: LaTeX Error: \begin{article} on input line
 20 ended by \end{sidewaystable}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
Dodatkowo: Warning message:
uruchomione polecenie '"C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf "RJwrapper.tex" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' otrzymało status 1 
Wykonywanie wstrzymane
```

**EDIT**

When I specify yaml in a way it is intended to work for `pdf_document` output

```
...
preamble: > 
   \usepackage{rotating}
output:
  rticles::rjournal_article:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
...
```

I receive an error that

```
Error in (function ()  : 
  unused (includes = list(in_header = "header.tex"))
```

**EDIT 2**

Even for an empty new document I get the same error

```
---
title: Capitalized Title Here
author:
  - name: Author One
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author1@work
  - name: Author Two
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author2@work
abstract: >
  An abstract of less than 150 words.
preamble: >
  % Any extra latex you need in the preamble
output:
  rticles::rjournal_article:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

Hello World
```

The `header.tex` document (which is in the same directory as saved empty new file) contains only 1 line:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
```

I am aware of `in_header` option in regular `pdf_document` output format (see even my files with [RMD extensions on github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarcinKosinski/SurvivalAnalysis/master/projekt12015.Rmd)) but it looks like to does not work with `rticles::rjournal_article`

**EDIT 3**

I am interested in adding other latex package than those that are included automatically in the `RJwrappter.tex` file which is generated after render of the .RMD file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{RJournal}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% load any required packages here


\begin{document}

%% do not edit, for illustration only
\sectionhead{Contributed research article}
\volume{XX}
\volnumber{YY}
\year{20ZZ}
\month{AAAA}

\begin{article}
  \input{rticle}
\end{article}

\end{document}
```

Anyone maybe knows how to solve this?
I am using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: What version of the (La)TeX system do you have? A base MickTeX?

Comment: MiKTeX 2.9 - I've edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question's old but I just had the same problem as Marcin and wanted to share my solution.

What worked for me was changing the template.tex file in the `rticles` package for the ASA article. At the top of the template, where they have all the other `\usepackage` commands, just add your package(s). I had the same problem that you did and neither of the typical solutions as provided in the first answer worked for me.

To edit the template file, go to the rticles directory in your package library folder (`.libPaths()` in R), then open up rmarkdown/templates/rjournal_article/resources/RJWrapper.tex. Add your package amongst all the others. This should work for any of the other *_article/resources/template.tex files.

Comment: Installing the package via Github has remedied the issue for me. See https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/pull/118/files. Apparently I hadn't updated the package in a while.  `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rticles")`

Answer (score 2):

No, that is wrong.  In the YAML header declare that you want an include.

See the [rmarkdown reference](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#advanced-customization):

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
      before_body: doc_prefix.tex
      after_body: doc_suffix.tex
---
```

I have used `header.tex` for this purpose in several documents.

**Edit:**  As you appear to get lost in the woods, here is a simplyfied example started from the default useR abstract template:

```
---
title: "Title of Your Submission"
author:
 - name: FirstNameA LastNameA
keywords: First, Second, ... up to 5 keywords
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: marcin_header.tex
---

Content to be added here.
```

which I coupled with the simplest possible header called `marcin_header.tex` (placed in the same directory) and containing just

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

Works for me.

**Edit 2:** Oh boy.

```
---
title: Capitalized Title Here
author:
  - name: Author One
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author1@work
  - name: Author Two
    affiliation: Affiliation
    address:
    - line 1
    - line 2
    email:  author2@work
abstract: >
  An abstract of less than 150 words.
preamble: >
  % Any extra latex you need in the preamble
  \usepackage{booktabs}
output: rticles::rjournal_article
---

## Introduction

Rest omitted.
```

Comment: I've tried to specify YAML like this @Dirk. I've edited my post with an error I received. In my first YAML specification there wasn't any error from rmarkdown but only `from latex`

Comment: Simplify, simplify, simplify.  Create an 'empty' example document where you just include one new package via the header to demonstrate to yourself that this works.  Then slowly add the feature you are currently fighting with in your document.  Once worked out, carry it over to your document.

Comment: I've tried that @Dirk before I have posted. Simple new document doesn't work and I receive the same error: `Error in (function ()  : 
  unused argument (includes = list(in_header = "header.tex"))` . I have an experience with rmarkdown and I am shocked that options for `pdf_document` do not work for `rticles::rjournal_article`

Comment: Works for `pdf_document`, does not work for `rticles::rjournal_article` .. In the question title there is `R Journal template`. Regular rmarkdowns for fine for me

Comment: I've edited my question once more to show you the code of my first approach to the problem. It looks exactly the same as yours approach in Edit 2 (except I use rotating package). Your code looks like to not generate any error because there is only plain text. My first approach also works with plain text, but when I specify a latex environment (the part that start with \begin{sidewaystable})) then it crashes with the error I posted in my original post (that can be still found after my first approach's code). Thanks for conversation :)

Comment: You can try to knit the document containing the same code as I in my `the first approach` section. Maybe it is the problem of the `texi2dvi` latex package - maybe I should have the newset version of it?

Comment: Besides booktabs package is included automatically in the RJournal templates. I am interested in adding new packages - rotating or lscape package for rotating tables or pages. It is shown in the `RJwrapper.tex` file after rendering the .Rmd file with rjournal-yaml-specification. Check my edit 3

Comment: It might be that the OP is using a package not present in his TeX (most likely the base MicTeX) distribution?

Comment: @SabDeM `rotating` latex package and `sidewaystable` environment works fine for me under regular tex compilation in i.e. tex-maker.

Answer (score 2):

As dash2 mentioned you need to edit one of your rticles templates to take advantage of the header-includes or preamble clause.  For example for the rticles::aea_article format the template could be in:
/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rticles/rmarkdown/templates/aea_article/resources/template.tex

This is for a linux system, but there's a location on your computer, whatever the OS, where R libraries are stored and you need to edit this file to include the snippet that dash2 provided.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this, as of Oct 16. What you need to do is find the relevant template and edit it to include the lines:

```
$for(header-includes)$                                                                                                 
$header-includes$                   
$endfor$
```

You can find the template by looking at the source code for e.g. `rjournal_article`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to include the float package by adding

`header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{float}`

into my yaml-header at the beginning of the frontiers-template