# Unable to make sense out of "Rstudio pdf knit fails with 'Environment Shaded undefined' error"

Tags: r, templates, latex, r-markdown

I am creating a report using the **rticles** package and I get the following error when knitting an rticle IEEE paper which includes code-chunks:

> output file: rticles_IEEE.knit.md
>      ! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined.

I tried to understand how to fix the issue and played around with this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052687/rstudio-pdf-knit-fails-with-environment-shaded-undefined-error). But I fail to see where to put the fix into the files created by knitting (e.g. mydoc.tex, IEEE_trans.cls).

Here is my minimal example:

````
---
title: Cool IEEE ArticleS
author:
  - name: Ray

abstract: |
   The abstract of my first IEEE paper with rmarkdown
output: rticles::ieee_article
---
Introduction
=============
This is the introduction. And here comes a cool code chunk.
```{r}
x <- seq(-3,3,0.1)
y <- x^3
plot(x,y)
```
````

---

**Notes**:

- It was commented that this is a potential duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052687/rstudio-pdf-knit-fails-with-environment-shaded-undefined-error). The problem with the answers given in that thread is that it does not explain where to make the changes.
- I fail to understand the pointer to [Yihui's fix](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/commit/a3e392593b464ba31a7eceb0cd60f7e0bd112798). 
  The aforementioned files, but also the knitted .tex does not come with labels of the form \makeatother or \makeatletter.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just suppress all code sections by setting `echo = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, my idea was to use 'specific' code chunks. Thus, my application (or question how to fix this) is part of the rare uses of this feature. I think as we move forward towards reproducible research more code chunks will be presented in academic papers (or at least their appendices). The references reported the echo = FALSE as a fix at the cost of not showing any chunks. I guess the solution is to create a format / layout definition for the shaded element and somehow append this to the template. As a novice to LATEX, I am simply lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall issue was that displaying a code chunk in the rticles IEEE paper throws an error pointing at the **undefined Shaded environment**.

The solution given in the [older post works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052687/rstudio-pdf-knit-fails-with-environment-shaded-undefined-error), if you add the following to the underlying  LaTeX `template.tex`. My problem was that I tried to edit the tex or cls template in the working directory. The Eureka-moment came when I stumbled over the following (related) [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503418/how-to-add-a-latex-package-to-r-journal-template-from-rticle-package-in-r).

For the **rticles** package, the `template.tex` is not located in your directory you work on the article R Markdown file. Instead, they are stored within the package library folder (i.e. the folder that `.libPaths()` uses). The file can be found in `rmarkdown/templates/` and search for the rticles folder you are using (in my case: `ieee_article`). In the `resources` sub-folder you will find the target template.tex. Make a copy of it, for recovery purposes.

Open the template.tex and insert the following anywhere before the LATEX command line `\begin{document}` (note: aka the preamble of that template.tex file). For example, I inserted it just before the \begin{document} line:

```
% code to insert to fix environment Shaded undefined issue with
% showing code chunks in rticle IEEE template.
$if(highlighting-macros)$
$highlighting-macros$
$endif$

\begin{document}
```

Save the change and go back to R/RStudio and your IEEE paper R Markdown file and hit the knit button. R code chunks will now be displayed (if you want to).

I have not tested it thoroughly, but this recipe should work for all rticle templates missing an environment definition for showing r-code chunks (i.e. `environment{Shaded}`)

Comment: Just worth pointing out that if you update the package, the file templates will be overwritten!

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. In fact, it requires to keep note of the change or follow your `header.tex` injection below. Great idea & wow - I guess it will take me a couple of decades to come up with such a header LATEX. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The fix has been incorporated in [the development version](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles) of the rticles package (the next CRAN version should be 0.6). Thanks!

Comment: @YihuiXie It is not in master branch yet... please add instructions for others on how to pull the develop branch and use it in R instead.

Comment: I don't know what made you believe it was not in the master branch, but it is in the master branch: https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/commit/bc8a23932e02cb4da517606fbc9abafcdc4fe08d If you open the link in my previous reply, you should see instructions on how to install the development version.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than duplicating the template, you can put the required code for allowing the highlighting in a separate `header.tex` file. This is essentially what replaces `$highlighting-macros$` when you include this in the template:

**header.tex**

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.77,0.63,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
```

Make a copy of this file in your directory and then refer to this header in the YAML:

````
---
title: Short Paper
output: 
  rticles::ieee_article:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---

# Introduction

This is the introduction. And here comes a cool code chunk.
```{r}
x <- seq(-3,3,0.1)
y <- x^3
plot(x,y)
```
````

[image]

> This approach should work for any template which includes the `$header-includes$ tag in the`template.tex`

Comment: Great stuff, Mickey. Thanks for sharing the LATEX to fix this problem elegantly in a separate `header.tex` file.

Comment: No problem! Please upvote the answer if you are happy with it :)

Comment: Done. Thanks again. Please bear with me as I will stay with the tweak of the `template.tex`. I know too little about LATEX, and your solution catapults me into another universe. I take note of your point that package updates will overwrite the fix in the `template.tex`. So I will keep a mental note that one can also inject the patch as a `header.tex` included via the YAML. It is probably my LATEX-novice status that makes me lend towards the 3 liner.